# How can we create an node with manual query in spring data neo4j?

Tags: spring, spring-data-neo4j

Create an node manually via repo interface but neo4j driver internally raise an exception as

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Invalid input '{': expected a parameter (line 1, column 22 (offset: 21))
"CREATE(a:Association {a.name:{0}}) RETURN true"
                       ^
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
    `@Repository
    public interface AssociationRepo extends Neo4jRepository {
 
     @Query("CREATE(a:Association {a.name:{0}}) RETURN a") -- what is wrong in this line ?
     Association addAssociation(String name);

    }`
```

Caller code :

```
   ` @Override
    public boolean addAssociationToCountry(String countryCode, Association association) {    
    
     repo.addAssociation(association.getName());    
     return true;

   }`
```

I checked whole of internet but didn't find any solution.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to the right syntax. The problem is the node name, you are using within the curly brackets.

Instead of `(a:Association {a.name:{0}})` it should be `(a:Association {name:{0}})` because the node boundaries already define that the properties belong to this very node.

Comment: Thanks for your reviewing issue and providing the comment.

Comment: Done with little correction to syntax as instead of (a:Association {name:{0}}) it should be (a:Association {name:0}). It starts working now. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I thought about the positional parameter and the `{}` syntax that were supported by Neo4j in the old 3.x versions. So I haven't spotted this.